# how to add elementor submission id in google sheets

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using integration with Google Sheets

But I want to add a new column in google sheet ( Submission ID )
am using elementor form , so i can see all submissions and every submission has a unique ID

am tried to make hidden field but it didn’t work

I want to add this ID in google sheet ? what should I do ?

Comment: Are you taking about Form id?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I need to use the submission_id in the reference of a mail.